# android - adding pic to the gallery app

Tags: android, image-gallery

I have an app that takes pictures and they are uploaded full-size. I want them to be shown in the gallery app. I'm using:

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(imagepath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

It works in 5.0 but not in 4.3. The `imagepath` is an absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try smthing like this...

```
private void galleryAddPhoto() {
    sendBroadcast(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                    Uri.parse("file://" + mCurrentFilteredPhotoPath))
    );
}
```

This method will add your file to gallery using it's position, where mCurrentFilteredPhotoPath is a String object